# 301 Permanent Redirect, Redirecting Incorrectly?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect traffic that attempts to access:
`cat.rs.allgames.com/cloud/11/services/titles/game5/console/file.json`

to:
`cat.cloud.allgames.com/titles/game5/console/file.json`

using a 301 permanent redirect in an .htaccess file, but it always sends me to:
`cat.cloud.allgames.comcloud/titles/game5/console/cloud/11/services/titles/game5/console/file.json`

which is nowhere near correct. What am I doing wrong?

My .htaccess is located in:
`cat.rs.allgames.com/cloud/11/services/titles/game5/console/file.json`

and looks like this:
`Redirect 301 / http://cat.cloud.allgames.com`

Comment: Suggest you switch to RedirectMatch as `Redirect` is just for exact matches of paths

Comment: I feel like I should be using ProxyPass for this. Forgive me for my inexperience but I'm unsure where to use my ProxyPass commands. Is it in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: I don't know how to use ProxyPass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rewrite module should do what you want! You need to make sure the rewrite module is enabled (for ubuntu: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`), then add this to your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/cloud/11/services/titles/(.*)$ http://cat.cloud.allgames.com/titles/$1 [R=301]
```

Here, the `^/cloud/11/services/titles/(.*)$` catches anything after the titles part of the URL. Then the `$1` at the end of the second part attaches what we caught to the end of the new URL. Finally, you can specify it as an external 301 rewrite to another server with the `[R=301]` flag!

Hope that works for you!